# Pass information from Foreground service to activity

Tags: java, android, service

I am trying to implement an service in my app and send messages(like bitmaps) from the service to MainActivity.  I have implemented the `onStartCommand()` function and started the service. I noticed that when I close the app the service continues(in the form of a notification). If I press any of the buttons on the notification that call is passed through `onStartCommand()` function. The problem is the app is closed! There are a couple of options at this stage:

- start the activity with `startActivity()`-this will result in the recall of the onCreate function in MainActivity which will recreate the service. The solution: check if the service is online(involves a very unprofessional loop through all active services). The problem: again how can I pass info from the service to this class(there's a Bundle parameter in `onCreate()` function,perhaps I can use that...but how)?

  ```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Log.i("", "In command");
      if(intent.getAction().equals("start")){
          createNotif();//notif+startForeground
      }else if(intent.getAction().equals("next")){
          Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
          dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          startActivity(dialogIntent);//pass data?
      }

      return START_STICKY;
  }
  ```
- instead of using `PendingIntent btnNext=PendingIntent.getService(this,0, btnNextIntent, 0);` use `PendingIntent pNext=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, btnNextIntent, 0);` which will directly start the activity(with the component class set to MainActivity). How can I use pass values with this method?

  ```
  //Next button
  Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundService.class);
  nextIntent.setAction("next");
  PendingIntent pNext=PendingIntent.getService(this,0, nextIntent, 0);//when button pressed the call is passed to onStartCommand()
  ```

  VS

  ```
  //Next button
  Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  nextIntent.setAction("next");
  PendingIntent pNext=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, nextIntent, 0);//when button pressed a new MainActivity instance is created...how can pass data to it?
  ```

How can Ipass a bitmap(for example) from a foreground service to MainActivity?

Comment: what is your exact question ?

Comment: How to pass a bitmap from a foreground service to MainActivity. If you any other suspicion about the purpose of the fragment I wrote please read it again. I have provided several ways to solve my own problem each with its own difficulties.

Comment: well, there are many ways, one of which is that you can use local broadcasts to communicate between your service and activity, or you can use bind mechanism for direct access to service methods from your activity..

Comment: also, note that, no matter how many times, you invoke `startService()`, if service is already running, it wont start again, instead, `onStartCommand()` will be triggered for subsequent calls to `startService()`.